# Create a column which increments value for changes in another row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns as below:

```
Var1Var2
a   28
b   28
d   28
f   29
f   29
e   30
b   30
m   30
l   30
u   31
t   31
t   31
```

I'd like to create a third column with values which increases by one for every change in value of another column.

```
Var1Var2Var3
a   28  1
b   28  1
d   28  1
f   29  2
f   29  2
e   30  3
b   30  3
m   30  3
l   30  3
u   31  4
t   31  4
t   31  4
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `category`

```
df.Var2.astype('category').cat.codes.add(1)
Out[525]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     4
10    4
11    4
dtype: int8
```

Updated

```
from itertools import groupby
grouped = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(df.Var2.tolist())]
np.repeat(range(len(grouped)),[len(x) for x in grouped])+1
```

Comment: Nice, but watch out. If you have 11, 11, 22, 22, 11, 11.... the result should be 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 but this would give 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.

Comment: @Mohnish that is repeat the number by group length . When you print out grouped you will see that is list of list then we repeat the range value by the length of sub list will give back your group number

Comment: @Wen Thanks! Sorry for deleting my previous comment. I figured it out myself, but then as soon as I deleted my comment I saw that you responded to it. Thanks a bunch though, really do appreciate your help!

Comment: @Mohnish yw happy coding

Comment: @Wen the values I am having in the first column are strings , and the new numbering is not preserving original index order. I am getting something like 3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2. I tried only the first method without the update. df length is too long to save them in a list

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti `pd.factorize(df['col'])[0]`

Comment: I don't have enough points to downvote, but this solution assumes that the values in Var2 arent' repeated. Be careful. I ended up using John Zwinck's answer.

Comment: @BENY what should I do if I need to apply it based on two columns? imagine I have one more dependency: column Var3. so a new column must be created based on changes in the Var2 and Var3. how do I call your method for it?

Comment: @emily.mi you can always try df.groupby(['var1','var2')].ngroup()+1

Answer (score 12):

You can compare `Var2` with its shifted-by-1 version:

```
v
   Var1  Var2
a     0    28
b     1    28
d     2    28
f     3    30
f     4    30
e     5     2
b     6     2
m     7     2
l     8     2
u     9     5
t    10     5
t    11     5

i = v.Var2    
v['Var3'] = i.ne(i.shift()).cumsum()

v
   Var1  Var2  Var3
a     0    28     1
b     1    28     1
d     2    28     1
f     3    30     2
f     4    30     2
e     5     2     3
b     6     2     3
m     7     2     3
l     8     2     3
u     9     5     4
t    10     5     4
t    11     5     4
```

Comment: what if Var2 is a string?

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti you mean, if it's a variable? Then you can use the [...] Syntax.

Comment: I mean if item of col `Var1` are all strings. some random word but some words are exactly the same.

Comment: This. Needs more upvotes, though.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
(df.Var2.diff() != 0).cumsum()
```

Comment: That works...thanks! However, how I go about doing the same if the values of the column were not sequential? (eg: Var2: 28,28,28,30,30,2,2,2,2,5,5,5 etc.)