# Merging rows in a pandas dataframe based on mutiple values

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

This is essentially related to [Merge values of a dataframe where other columns match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690254/merge-values-of-a-dataframe-where-other-columns-match) but since this question was already answered and I didn't figure out the correct modification for the different problem, I opened this new thread. Hopefully that is okay. To the question. I have the following data

```
 date              car_brand    color     city      stolen
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      red       paris     False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      red       london    False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      red       munich    False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      red       madrid    False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      red       rome      False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      blue      berlin    False 
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      blue      tokyo     False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      blue      peking    False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      white     liverpool False 
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      white     oslo      False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      white     barcelona False
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      white     miami     False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      red       paris     False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      red       london    False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      red       munich    False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      red       madrid    False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      red       rome      False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      blue      berlin    False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      blue      tokyo     False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      blue      peking    False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      white     liverpool False 
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      white     oslo      False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      white     barcelona False
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      white     miami     False 
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      red       paris     False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      red       london    False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      red       munich    False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      red       madrid    True
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      red       rome      False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      blue      berlin    False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      blue      tokyo     False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      blue      peking    False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      white     liverpool False 
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      white     oslo      False
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      white     barcelona False 
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      white     miami     False 
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      red       paris     False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      red       london    False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      red       munich    False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      red       madrid    False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      red       rome      False 
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      blue      berlin    False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      blue      tokyo     False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      blue      peking    False 
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      white     liverpool False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      white     oslo      False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      white     barcelona False
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      white     miami     False
```

I know what to create a dataframe from that based in the following way: if for consecutive days the boolean "stolen" matches for all the entries, then I want to merge the date column. For example in the above example the boolean entries match for "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-02". So in total I would like to end up with the following:

```
 date                             car_brand    color     city      stolen
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      red       paris     False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      red       london    False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      red       munich    False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      red       madrid    False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      red       rome      False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      blue      berlin    False 
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      blue      tokyo     False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      blue      peking    False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      white     liverpool False 
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      white     oslo      False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      white     barcelona False
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      white     miami     False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      red       paris     False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      red       london    False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      red       munich    False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      red       madrid    True
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      red       rome      False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      blue      berlin    False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      blue      tokyo     False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      blue      peking    False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      white     liverpool False 
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      white     oslo      False
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      white     barcelona False 
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      white     miami     False 
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      red       paris     False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      red       london    False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      red       munich    False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      red       madrid    False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      red       rome      False 
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      blue      berlin    False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      blue      tokyo     False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      blue      peking    False 
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      white     liverpool False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      white     oslo      False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      white     barcelona False
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      white     miami     False
```

Comment: Same solution works from my understanding...   why is 3-Jan, Porsche, Paris, red not with 1st & 3rd in required output?  all are not stolen

Comment: Same solution works from my understanding: I tried it but it didn't work for me.

 why is 3-Jan, Porsche, Paris, red not with 1st & 3rd in required output? all are not stolen:
That's true. But I want to combine the consecutive days where ALL stolen booleans are equal. So on the third there was a stolen porsche (city and color doesn't matter). So I want the output for the entire 3rd of Jan separately.

Comment: @RobRaymond Same solution works from my understanding:
The problem is not matter how I use groupby, i will end up with a dataframe that has the row where solen = True as a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to keep short,  code does not have building of dataframe from sample data.

Key technique is a new column which changes on **date** **stolen**. [increment on value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492685/create-a-column-which-increments-value-for-changes-in-another-row)

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

# require new group when there is a stolen car in any date
df2 = (df.groupby("date")["stolen"].max().to_frame()
 .reset_index()
 .assign(stolen_grp=lambda dfa: (dfa.stolen.diff() != 0).cumsum())
 .drop(columns="stolen")
)

# put stolen_grp back into dataframe
df = df.merge(df2, on="date")

# same technique, breaking on days a car has been stolen
(
    df
    .groupby([c for c in df.columns if c!="date"])["date"]
    # only include if first date or if it's a consequetive date
    .agg(lambda x: [xx for i,xx in enumerate(x) if i==0 or xx==(list(x)[i-1]+pd.DateOffset(1))])
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="stolen_grp")
)
```

### sample output

```
car_brand color   city  stolen                                       date
  porsche  blue berlin   False [2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-02 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue berlin   False                      [2020-01-03 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue berlin   False                      [2020-01-04 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue peking   False [2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-02 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue peking   False                      [2020-01-03 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue peking   False                      [2020-01-04 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue  tokyo   False [2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-02 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue  tokyo   False                      [2020-01-03 00:00:00]
  porsche  blue  tokyo   False                      [2020-01-04 00:00:00]
  porsche   red london   False [2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-02 00:00:00]
```